# Is there an alternative to this logic to produce different display strings?

Tags: c#

Suppose we have a class that stores three counts and has a display method which returns a string. If the any of the counts is zero doesn't display it. Only display Count3 if there is a Count1 or a Count2. Show each count on a separate line where it shows x Count1, x Count2, etc.

```
    public class Item
    {
        public int Count1 { get; set; }
        public int Count2 { get; set; }
        public int Count3 { get; set; }

        public string ShowCounts()
        {
            string display = string.Empty;

            if (this.Count1 > 0 && this.Count2 > 0)
            {
                display = $"{this.Count1} Count1 \n {this.Count2} Count2";
            }
            if (this.Count1 > 0 && this.Count2 == 0)
            {
                display = $"{this.Count1} Count1";
            }
            if (this.Count1 == 0 && this.Count2 > 0)
            {
                display = $"{this.Count2} Count2";
            }
            if (this.Count3 > 0 && (this.Count1 > 0 || this.Count2 > 0))
            {
                display = $"{display} \n {this.Count3} Count3";
            }

            return display;
        }
   }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: In the question heading. Is there a better way than this if/else logic?

Comment: If your code actually works it might be more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (which oddly enough is not avaiable in flags)

Comment: That's not `if`/`else`. It's just `if`/`if`/`if`. I think your last `if` and your first `if` may overlap.

Comment: @user6144226 I think I remember a discussion about that (missing flag) and if I remember correctly this was because it became a "bad habit" to redirect questions there although they were not at all suited for codereview.

Comment: Fixed the mistakes. I'm asking is there a better method to produce the same result.

Comment: @Fildor However you can flag it for moderators with a note about review. This question is a perfecr candidate for it.

Comment: You could configure the display message in the property `set` procedure. There's plenty of other, maybe better, ways you *could* store the counts in a list or dictionary etc. and then you would have some other ways of checking for the zero-values, rather than an `==0` test, but which is "best" seems kinda subjective.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's correct. You can do that of course.

Comment: What do you expect as the output if `count1` is 0, `count2` is 0 and `count3` is 5?

Comment: It would return string.empty if count1 is 0 and count2 is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach. *Note in particular that we only include `Count3` if either `Count1` or `Count2` is positive, as per the original code.*

```
public string ShowCounts()
{
    var results = new List<string>();

    if (this.Count1 > 0)
    {
        results.Add($"{this.Count1} Count1");
    }
    if (this.Count2 > 0)
    {
        results.Add($"{this.Count2} Count2");
    }
    if (results.Any() && this.Count3 > 0)
    {
        results.Add($"{this.Count3} Count3");
    }

    return results.Any() ? string.Join("\n", results) : "";
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good one. It allows some flexibility like if you want to use HTML line breaks instead of "\n". You could use string.Join("<br >", results)

Answer (score 1):

The most *robust* method would be to add an attribute (`ShowCountAttribute`) and have reflection load that attribute and call it a day.

In fact, here's a quick example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ShowCountAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `ShowCounts`:

```
var counts =
    this.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(ShowCountAttribute)))
        .Select(prop => new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<ShowCountAttribute, int>>(prop.Name, new Tuple<ShowCountAttribute, int>((ShowCountAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ShowCountAttribute), true).First(), (int)prop.GetValue(this))));

if (counts.Any(x => x.Value.Item2 > 0 && x.Value.Item1.Required))
    return string.Join("\n", counts.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Item2 > 0).OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.Item1.Order).Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Value.Item2} {kvp.Key}"));
else
    return string.Empty;
```

It's also trivial to define your own `Name` on the `ShowCustomAttribute` class, that if set will override the property name. I leave that usage up to you. If no `Required` counts are included, then it sends `string.Empty`.

I used `Tuple<,>` here since C#7.0 has wonderful support for them.

Comment: I like it but it's a little more complex than what I needed.

Comment: @MattLaCrosse You're performing a complex action. You can't think about what is or isn't complex - you have to think about what is most future proof. If you were on [CodeReview.SE] I would tell you to scrap this whole method, because it mixes two different display concerns. You should have two steps for this process: acquire the list of *valid* counts, and print them. You currently have one *very* convoluted step, this solution allows you to split them to the appropriate steps.

Answer (score 1):

I know appending a fixed number of lines using += is faster than using StringBuilder, but I think not having to append "\n" all the time makes the code more legible

```
public string ShowCounts()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();  

    bool count1 = this.Count1 > 0;
    bool count2 = this.Count2 > 0;

    if (count1)
        builder.AppendLine($"{this.Count1} Count1");

    if (count2)
        builder.AppendLine($"{this.Count2} Count2");

    if (this.Count3 > 0 && (count1 || count2))
        builder.AppendLine($"{this.Count3} Count3");

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ShowCounts()
    {
        string display = string.Empty;

        if (this.Count1 > 0)
        {
            display = $"{this.Count1} Count1";
        }
        if (this.Count2 > 0)
        {
            if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(display) ) display += "\n";
            display += $"{this.Count2} Count2";
        }
        if (this.Count3 > 0)
        {
            if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(display) )
            {  // == Count3 > 0 && ( Count1 > 0 || Count2 > 0 )
               display += $"\n{this.Count3} Count3";
            }
        }

        return display;
    }
```

Untested, but should do the trick if it's really only about those "if"s.

Comment: This is not bad.

Comment: Thanks :) Actually, I like mjwills' answer better than my own, though.